# How to make an tuple that contains elements 1,2,3,...100?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tuples

Sorry I know this is a very easy question, I want to make a tuple that contains 1,2,3,4,...,100. Should I first make numpy array and then convert the numpy to tuple? If yes, how can I make such a thing as a numpy first?

Comment: `print(tuple(range(1, 101)))`  ?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to create a tuple containing these numbers?  Chances are there is a better solution to whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @SvenMarnach It is being used for grid search cross-validation for a neural network, I want it to try values 1,...,100 for the number of neurons in the first layer.

Comment: One use case is if you want a `dict` key, since you can't use a list.

Comment: @Sus20200 You can most likely pass in `range(1, 101)` instead of the tuple containing these values.

Comment: @user4343502 Hmm, it seems rather unlikely that someone wants to use a tuple containing the number from 1 to 100 as a dictionary key. :)  (And, somewhat off topic, you can use a Python 3 range object as a dictionary key, too.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach Agreed, it's probably unlikely.  Doesn't seem particularly unpythonic, though.  One real-life scenario is mapping different groups of users to specific chatrooms, although this can be used in any scenario where you want to map a specific set of objects to some other type of thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it like:

```
x = tuple(range(1, 101))
```

Or, using NumPy:

```
x = tuple(np.arange(1, 101))
```

Comment: Thanks, how can we make them increase by an arbitrary number like 2?  1,3,5,7,...

Comment: you just have to add a third parameter: instead of `range(1, 101)` you write `range(1, 101, 2)`, you can replace the 2 by the step size you want

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to create a `range()` and turn it into a tuple:

```
tuple(range(1, 101))
```

In general, you shouldn't even need to turn it into a tuple, though – you can use the `range` object directly.

Comment: Thanks, how can we make them increase by an arbitrary number like 2?  1,3,5,7,...

Comment: @Sus20200: Anything that you can describe in a sequence can be turned into a tuple. So `1,3,5,7...` would be `tuple(range(1,[ending value +1,2))` or `tuple(map(int,'1357'))` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should *not* use numpy for that. As a general rule converting between numpy and python sequences is pretty slow:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> import numpy as np
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=1000000)
>>> 
>>> timeit("tuple(np.arange(1,101))", **kwds)
4.895919734146446
>>> timeit("tuple(range(1,101))", **kwds)
1.0187234980985522
>>> timeit("*range(1,101),", **kwds)
1.3246291619725525
```